# How do I load data to a list from a dataReader?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am tryin to add data to my list object.
For a string, I just say, this.name = myDaraReader["test"]toTring();  How do I go about doing that for a list?

Comment: Please someone fix the text (dat->data,Dara->Data,Tring->String) before my brain fries. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is more to this than I see but is there a reason you can't just write

theList.Add(myDataReader["test"].toString());

I think that will work unless I am missing something..

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
nameList.Add(myDaraReader["test"]toTring());
```

**//Note: I just added what you typed above instead of fixing the syntax.**

Here are a few links for reading on the two topics [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(VS.71).aspx)