# Idatareader to List

Tags: linq, c#-3.0, idatareader

Using Linq is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
 IDataReader reader = qSeats.ExecuteReader();
            var seats = new List<int>();
            using (IDataReader reader = qSeats.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    seats.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetInt32(0)));
                }
            }
```

I saw: [How do I load data to a list from a dataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003480/how-do-i-load-data-to-a-list-from-a-datareader)
However this is the same code I have above, and it seems like there could be faster ways.
Like using Linq or seats.AddRange() or some kind of ToList()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataReader is read-only, forward-only stream of data from a database. The way you are doing it is probably the fastest.

> Using the DataReader can increase application performance both by
>   retrieving data as soon as it is available, rather than waiting for
>   the entire results of the query to be returned, and (by default)
>   storing only one row at a time in memory, reducing system overhead.
>   [Retrieving Data Using the DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Except that it appears to be executing twice